# Inoculation vs. vaccination

Tags: microbiology, terminology, vaccination

Is there any actual difference between inoculation and vaccination or are these terms interchangeable?

In case the difference exists, would it be correct to say that inoculation is purposefully infecting a person with a pathogen in a controlled way, even when the person is already infected, to induce immunity while vaccination is administering dead or weakened pathogens to a healthy person as a preventive measure to check future infections?

Also, would it be correct to say that vaccination is an advanced form of inoculation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both are forms of immunisation.

Inoculation is exactly that. A live organism is introduced in a controlled way, so as to minimise the risk of infection, and is essentially the same process followed by many people in history.  It is inherently risky.

Vaccination is introducing a weakened version of the pathogen, so that the immune response is triggered and the body is prepared to fight the actual pathogen if necessary. This was pioneered by Edward Jenner, wherein he noticed that cowpox (related to smallpox) immunised the milkmaids against smallpox.

Comment: Cowpox (*Vaccinia*) is not "weakened smallpox" (*Variola*). They are entirely separate, but related, viruses.

Comment: @MattDMo True. It slipped my mind. Corrected the post.

Comment: Interestingly, the word _vaccination_ is derived from _vacca_,  the Latin word for cow.

Comment: I'd maybe clarify. A vaccination isn't necessarily the whole pathogen, like the tetanus vaccine is the injection of a tetanus toxoid prepared from the toxin, so you build antibodies toward that (inactive) structure. Likewise, Gardasil is simply inactive viral proteins from HPV. Flu vaccine, however, is indeed attenuated flu strains. I would argue the fundamental difference is inoculation used live organisms where this isnt necessarily true of a vaccine in the modern sense.

Comment: @RoverEye That helped. However, I am still not sure if it would be correct to say that vaccination is an advanced form of inoculation.

Answer (score 5):

In a general sense and as per the current scientific parlance, inoculation is used to mean introduction of a microbe to a system. This can refer to immunization procedures as well as for addition of a microbe to a culture medium in microbiological procedures.

Vaccination specifically refers to an immunization procedure which may involve attenuated pathogens, inactivated toxins (tetanus toxoid) or even specific proteins which are expressed in a lab microbe using recombinant DNA technology (as in case of hepatitis-B vaccine).

Etymology of both the terms, however, pertains to smallpox immunization. "Inoculation" is derived *from Latin inoculatus, past participle of inoculare "graft in, implant a bud or eye of one plant into another* <sup>[[1]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=inoculate)</sup>. In this procedure, the immunization was done by infecting an individual with a smallpox pustule from a patient (in a way grafting the pox).

"Vaccination" comes from the latin word *vacca* which means cow. This refers to the vaccine that Edward Jenner derived from cowpox.

Comment: This is much better answer alhough seems to be less liked. When we transfer microbes to a petri dish, it is called innoculation, although it has nothing to do with immunuty.

Answer (score 2):

If you got your flu shots you could say that you got your vaccination, your immunization or your inoculation 
and you would be correct with all three words.  However the words do have different yet overlapping meanings.

Vaccination is the act of administering a vaccine. Although the word "vaccine" started with Jenner's cow pox it was expanded by Pasteur to mean all inoculations intended to perform immunity. The vaccine is a pathogen or toxin rendered survivable either by altering it or,  most commonly, by using minimal amounts.

Immunization is any part of the process of becoming immune, but particularly the part taking place within your body as a response to a vaccine. You could gain immunity without a vaccine, and you could get a vaccination without gaining immunity.

Inoculation is a wider term for any transfer of tiny amounts of a material to a living organism, but the word has expanded beyond biology and is used in varied ways. An inoculation does not need to be for the purpose of immunization although immunizing is the most common usage. Intentionally infecting a lab mouse with a disease is inoculation but not intended to immunize. The original use of the word was to graft seeds (also called "eyes" thus the "ocula" etymology) which has nothing to do with immunity.

In some medical circles, inoculation is skin administered,  while vaccine is oral or both oral and skin, but there is no such concise definition by universal agreement.